# C++ Creating Global Reference of an Object

Tags: c++, qt, object-reference, global-object

I am trying to create a global reference of an object but it seems fails or I am getting another error in Qt C++.

I have a class called 'System' which holds many objects as members. I want to access System's members from everywhere include members of System. Here is my code below:

```
// System.h
class System
{
public:

    Obj1* m_obj1;
    Obj2* m_obj2;

    System();
    ~System();

    static System* GetGlobalReference();
}


// System.cpp
static System* GlobalReference = 0;

System::System()
{
    if (!GlobalReference) GlobalReference = this;

    m_obj1 = new Obj1();
    m_obj2 = new Obj2();
}

System* System::GetGlobalReference()
{
    return GlobalReference;
}

// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    System* system = new System();

    MainWindow window;
    window.showMaximized();

    return app.exec();
}

//Obj1.h
class Obj1 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Obj1() : QObject() {}
    ~Obj1();

public slots:
    void Import();
}

// Obj1.cpp
void Obj1::Import()
{
    QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            0,
            QString("Import file..."),
            QString("C:\\"),
            QString("JPEG File (*.jpg)"),
            0,
            0);
    if (System::GetGlobalReference())
        System::GetGlobalReference()->m_obj2->Import(path); // error here
    else
        // System::GlobalReference is null

}
```

It seems reference is not null but I get an error during runtime "Access violation reading location..." What is wrong?

Btw Obj1 is a QObject and Import method is a public slot, can the error be related with this?

Edit: Debuugger last step is here in QGenericAtomic.h

```
T load(const T &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
{
    return _q_value; // -> Debugger stops here
}
```

Edit2: I've used Singleton pattern as the answers says but my problem still continues.

```
System::GetInstance()->GetObj1()->Import(path); // after this line
```

in "_q_value" it says ""

Comment: For your System class, you should use the Singleton pattern.

Comment: Thanks for this quick, consistent answer.

Comment: You show us plenty of code, but not what Obj2 is. Actually I am wondering why your code compiles. Does `GetObj1()` returns an Obj1? If so, you call `Import(path)` in it. `void Import();` is implemented without parameter. Which function is `Import(path)`? If you want us to help you to debug your code, show us your code. Not only the parts where you think the bug is. If you were able to pinpoint the problem zone yourself, you would not need asking us.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've solved my problem. The problem was caused by Obj1->Import method but during debug in qt, debugger is not accessing inside the method when I press F11(Step Into). I cannot figure it out why?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to have global variables, I would recommend using a [singleton](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1921/Singleton-Pattern-its-implementation-with-C) instead.

Global variables in C++ are declared using `extern`, not static. See the [reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this quick, consistent answer. Is Error caused for this decleration type?

Comment: I've used singleton pattern but problem still continues

Answer (score 2):

**If you want only one instance of your `System` class**, you should use the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

But, the Singleton pattern should be used when you want an unique instance of a class, the reason should not be when you want to have an object global. Even if using this pattern, your instance is accessible from everywhere.

Look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/1394283) about Singleton design pattern, it may be useful in your case.

Also, in C++ the declaration of global variable is done with `extern`, not `static`.